# Img in full height plus multi line text together in one line using inline-block?

Tags: html, css, inline

I am curious how to set-up this markup using only inline-block property(i got it working with flex in 10secs, but still wanna know);

https://codepen.io/antongrekov/pen/BajmryQ

Here is a pen:

```
.wrapper
    img(src="https://logomaster.ai/static/media/gallery002.936afb9d.png")
    p Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus commodi fuga illo cumque perspiciatis optio quod tot423am quibusdam architecto ea?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus commodi fuga illo cumque perspiciatis optio quod totam quibusdam architecto ea?

.wrapper
    background: #333
    border: 1px dashed gray
    max-width: 500px
img 
    display: inline-block
    width: 150px
    margin-right: 1rem
    vertical-align: middle
p
    display: inline-block
    width: 60%
    vertical-align: middle
```

Requirements are that img always **full height** of parent container, so that text doesn't go under img. Img and text are always in some same height boxes, if text is to large it grows in lines enlarging height. Img is fixed width(let it be 150px), paragraph takes rest space. If you go to mobile view and reduce width at some point there won't be enough space for img and p altogether so as any regular inline element it will wrap to next line. What i want is at this poing paragraph will increase in height staying same line with img and img will be full height preventing text under.

I tried applying *white-space: nowrap* to parent container and *white-space: normal* to b3, but that results in text cropping. Somewhy text won't grow multiline, i guess may be cuz of inline-block property.

How do you solve this using only inline-block or inline display property.

Comment: https://codepen.io/antongrekov/pen/BajmryQ

Comment: making .wrapper nowrap and paragraph white-space: normal along with % width gives almost what i want - text stays same line with img, grows vertically in height and rest, yet it crops on extra small width instead of growing more in height

Comment: float: left not suitable cuz it disables vertical align property

Comment: magic of stackoverflow: find a solution. in that case you need to set up width for p correctly. using calc function. width: calc(100% - 150px - 1rem), with substituting fixed img width and margin right of image. but yet there are some small overflow for text, cant understand why. update pen.

Comment: and it's not about border of .wrapper. somewhy text goes out of box for 2 px or so. removeing border for wrapper or making it box-sizing: border-box doesnt help

Comment: Last update. So problem now is that somewhy there are some 1-2 extra pixels for paragraphs. And i think i know what are they now :D spaces, right :) ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set width according to fixed width of img and margins of img.
width: calc(100% - 150px - 1rem) should do it along with setting both img and paragraph to inline-block. To prevent wrapping you need to use white-space: nowrap on parent container and set white-space: normal on paragraph. Remember to clear spaces between img and p tags, they should not have even line-breaks between them <img ...><p...> or if they do have line break set font-size on parent container to 0.